# Android P compilation error

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am compiling Android P but cant fix this error:

```
x-androideabi/bin   -std=gnu99 -mthumb -Os   -Wall -Werror -Wno-sign-compare -fPIC -D_USING_LIBCXX   -Werror=int-to-pointer-cast -Werror=pointer-to-int-cast -Werror=address-of-temporary -Werror=return-type -Wno-tautological-constant-compare -Wno-null-pointer-arithmetic -Wno-enum-compare -Wno-enum-compare-switch -MD -MF /home/carlos/sources/androidexperience/out/target/product/gt510wifi/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libclearsilverregex_intermediates/android/regex/bb_regex.d -o /home/carlos/sources/androidexperience/out/target/product/gt510wifi/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libclearsilverregex_intermediates/android/regex/bb_regex.o external/busybox/android/regex/bb_regex.c"
external/busybox/android/regex/bb_regex.c:2931:12: error: unused variable 'num_regs' [-Werror,-Wunused-variable]
  unsigned num_regs = 0;
           ^
external/busybox/android/regex/bb_regex.c:5476:20: error: unused parameter 'preg' [-Werror,-Wunused-parameter]
    const regex_t *preg;
                   ^
2 errors generated.
[ 11% 6523/57956] -e Prepare config for busybox binary
find: ‘/home/carlos/sources/androidexperience/out/target/p
```

If I use `-Werror` can fix first error but cant fix second error.

Same error using `-Wunused-parameter`

https://github.com/LineageOS/android_external_busybox/blob/cm-14.1/android/regex/bb_regex.c#L5405

Any idea?

Comment: Embedding your error message in the question itself (not an external link) would be much more helpful and make it more likely that you'll get help with your question.

Comment: cant add It, too long @vealkind

Answer (score 2):

This is because Android Pie took a new strategy: every project's warning will all be treated as error (`-Wall -Werror` appends to every C/C++ compiler command lines). Only those projects which are included in variable `ANDROID_WARNING_ALLOWED_PROJECTS` can have warnings ignored. Notice that this variable is controlled by Soong.

Solution is: open `build/soong/cc/config/global.go`, and add BusyBox's entry into the list `WarningAllowedProjects`:

```
        // Directories with warnings from Android.bp files.
        WarningAllowedProjects = []string{
                "device/",
                "vendor/",
+               "external/busybox",
        }
```

Save, `make clean`, and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue in Android P today.
I add "__unused"  before the "const regex_t *preg;"  and fixed.

`__unused const regex_t *preg;`